# try and catch error during using firebase authentication

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, firebase-authentication, try-catch

My try and catch is not working the catch func is not handling the error, I have copied the same code recommended by google to use firebase for authentication but it's not working:
[image]

I am expecting my catch func to handle the firebase auth exception errors thrown by the try block

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that VSCODE is doing

you can untick the "Uncaught Exceptions" box under "Breakpoints" on the left

[image: VsCode Image]

i think its a replicated question, the answer is available here: [Dart / Flutter - Debugger stops on caught exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802675/dart-flutter-debugger-stops-on-caught-exceptions)

Comment: great.
if solved the issue,set this  answer as correct.